# iPhone cocos2d - Use the same animation actions for many sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hey,
I'm writing game for iPhone, using cocos2d framework.

I have 100 sprites and I want to run on them the same animation.
Do I have to create 100 separate actions for each sprite, or can I create one action and use it on every sprite?

Answer (score 0):

One method which I follow is that I create an derived class from sprite class and assign actions in the class initialization .

For example I have to generate 10-100 enemy sprite

I'll make a class enemyActoor.mm derived from CCSprite

their I keep a function

```
+(void)initwithParamters:(CCPoint)spwanPoint  frames:(NSString *)plist{

mummyActor *tempInstance =[mummyActor spriteWithWatever suites ur reqirment];

//do all stuff here 
//load actions

return tempInstance;

} 
//other methods to call actions or access mutators
```

when I need to generate these enemies I create n NSMuTableArray enemyLoaded and keep all instance in this array ....

when applying various pathfinding algo or rules as per game I access each objects from these array ///

Sorry for poor english but this is the best way I found till now to get work done without asking anyone ;)

Comment: Hmm. I find out something. I have definied "action", and I use this action to animate my sprite. But when I want to run later another animation on this same sprite I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS. But when I use "action", and then do sth like that: "action = [Animation newAnim];", and then run on this sprite, everything works fine. But I dont want to create new action during the game, but in init function, and then run it.

Comment: Hi, I know that this question is a bit old, but I'm currently have the same question and just wanted to check if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make one action using the `id` and then assign your sprites that one action. Like this

```
id myAction = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.2f position:myPoint];
id mySecondAction = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.2f angle:myAngle];
id actionSequence = [CCSequence actions: myAction, mySecondAction, nil];
```

Then run through all your sprites and attach the action. If you have an array us the `for in` methodology as it is faster.

```
for (CCSprites mySprites in myArray) {   
     //attach actions to sprites code here

}
```